# eXist-db: username/password when connecting from Java applications with the XML:DB API

Tags: java, exist-db

I want to insert data from my Java application to a secured eXist-db

I found this document: https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/devguide_xmldb but it does not have guide for passing username and password.

I tried

```
database.setProperty("username", "admin");
database.setProperty("password", "admin");
```

But this exception is still thrown:

```
org.xmldb.api.base.XMLDBException: Failed to invoke method parse in class org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: Write permission is not granted on the Collection
```

Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find examples of using eXist-db's XML:DB API in the eXist book, for reference the example Java applications code is here: https://github.com/eXist-book/book-code/tree/master/chapters/integration/xmldb-client

Specifically, you might find this helpful:

https://github.com/eXist-book/book-code/blob/master/chapters/integration/xmldb-client/xmldb-client-store/src/main/java/exist/book/example/xmldb/client/StoreApp.java#L56